# apache2 silent redirection not working as expected

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a web server using apache2, and I want to silently redirect some pages.
So if an user try to access "http://website.com/test.php", the page at "http://website.com/fool.php" will be used instead. And i need to do that for several pages, not just test.php.

I though I could use the mod_rewrite module for this purpose, but I cant get it working.
I tried adding in apache2.conf, so i could have at least just a redirection for now (not silent):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/test.php$" "/fool.php"
```

or

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase "/var/www"

    RewriteRule "^/test.php$" "/fool.php"
</Directory>
```

This result in the test.php not being redirected at all (it still can be accessed), but also, it breaks my custom 404 and 403 pages with the error "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.".

Apache2 is not complaining about the syntax when i restart it.

Setting it in my sites-enabled config leads to the same result.

Note that the goal is not to prevent the direct access to test.php, and the request must result in a 200 success code.

There may be something i do not understand, because searching on the net, it looks like it's the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try an alternative method: use the .htaccess file. (place the file in the root directory of your site)

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/test.php$ /fool.php  [L]
```

Comment: I can still access test.php, but this does not break my custom error pages.
Maybe something is making the entire feature not working? I checked It's enabled.